# JAVA constructor FileInputStream(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Tags: java

## Reading a property file from other path and print in the Console

I am trying to Print the values getting from the property file and printing it to the console but i am getting this error like---->Error Msg :"Cannot find symbol and Constructor FileInputStream(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) " error is throwing
how to fix this ?

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;// Adding the Class to read file
    import java.io.IOException; // Adding the Class to avoid Exception while   reading the file
    import java.io.InputStream;// Adding the Class to read file
    import java.util.Properties;// Adding the Class to read Property file
    import java.lang.String;
    class readPropFile
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {   
           Properties prop = new Properties();
           InputStream in = null;
        try //reading a file here
        {
        in = new FileInputStream("Sample.properties","D:/MYJAVAPRGMS/Property); // Setting the file name and path to read
        prop.load(in);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("emp_Id"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("first_Name"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("last_Name"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("org_Name"));  // reading the Values using Key          
        
      }
    
      catch (IOException io) // catch the Exception 
       {
         io.printStackTrace();
       }
        
  finally // Finally block to take the value 
         {
             if (in != null)
                    {
                      try {
                             in.close();
                         } 
                      catch (IOException e)
                                         {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                         }
                   }
        
              }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't try to use a constructor that doesn't exist? `FileInputStream` has three constructors, and they all take a single argument.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? Especially after studying the Javadoc of the called method?

Comment: try using `in = new FileInputStream("D:/MYJAVAPRGMS/Property/Sample.properties/Sample.properties");` .

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;// Adding the Class to read file
    import java.io.IOException; // Adding the Class to avoid Exception while   reading the file
    import java.io.InputStream;// Adding the Class to read file
    import java.util.Properties;// Adding the Class to read Property file
    import java.lang.String;
    class one
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {   
           Properties prop = new Properties();
           InputStream in = null;
        try //reading a file here
        {
        in = new FileInputStream("D://MYJAVAPRGMS//Property//sample.properties");
        prop.load(in);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("emp_Id"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("first_Name"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("last_Name"));// reading the Values using Key
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("org_Name"));  // reading the Values using Key          

      }

      catch (IOException io) // catch the Exception 
       {
         io.printStackTrace();
       }

  finally // Finally block to take the value 
         {
             if (in != null)
                    {
                      try {
                             in.close();
                         } 
                      catch (IOException e)
                                         {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                         }
                   }

              }

        }
    }
```